# PHP Object definitions cached? Trouble deleting methods with reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I am working on an object to allow us to modify PHP files containing PHP objects. (Specifically, they are Doctrine entity files that we have to modify.)

Anyway, without the boring details here is what is happening. I am first finding the location of the class file, and INCLUDEing it. I then create an instance of the class, and a class reflector, using the the code below. As you can see, when I instantiate the object and the reflector, I also call a method to load the text of the class from disk into a string, and another method to break that string into an array by lines.

```
public function loadClass()
   if(!class_exists($this->class_name)) {
      $this->error = "Class name: '$this->class_name' was not found.";}
   else {
      //Class is found. Load it and populate properties
      $this->oClass          = new $this->class_name;
      $this->oRClass         = new \ReflectionClass($this->oClass);
      $this->source_file     = $this->oRClass->getFileName();
      $this->error           = "";
      $this->class_namespace = $this->oRClass->getNamespaceName();
      $this->getClassText();  //Load class code from source file
      $this->getClassArray(); //Load class text into array
   }
}
```

I then use a function called "`deleteMethod()`" to remove the PHP code for a specific method as follows: `$this->deleteMethod("badMethod");`. This function then finds the start line and then end line of the method in question, deletes the line, saves the class PHP code back to disk, and runs '`loadClass()`' again to re-parse the updated object so it is ready for more editing. Below is an excerpt of the "`deleteMethod()`" function.

```
$oMethod = $this->oRClass->getMethod($meth_name);       //Get a refection method object 
$oMethod->setAccessible(true);                          //In case method is private
$start_line = $oMethod->getStartLine() -1;              //Line method starts at
$length = $oMethod->getEndLine() - $start_line + 1      //Number of lines in method
array_splice($this->class_array, $start_line, $length); //Hack lines out of array
$this->class_text = implode("\n", $this->class_array);  //Convert array back to a string
$this->saveClassText();                              //Save updated code back to disk.
$this->loadClass();                                     //Reload and reparse for consistancy
```

The problem is that the object apears to be cached somewhere. When I run the `$this->deleteMethod("anotherBadMethod");` function again, it no longer returns the proper start/end lines for the next method to be deleted. After some checking, it became obvious that what is happening is that the when I try to get the start/end line for the next method to be deleted, PHP is still using the OLD class definition. It does NOT seem to "see" that some code has been deleted from the file, and the line numbers have changed. As you can see, I am instanciating both the object, and the reflection object every time we run `loadClass()`. And yes, I tried setting them to NULL before instanciating them.

I have also verified that PHP sees the class definition file properly. Meaning that even though the file was included, the reflection `getFileName();` does see that the class is defined where it should be.

Soooo.... Is PHP caching the definition of the class that I have included in memory? If so, how do I flush that cash? Is there some way to "undefine", that class, and reload it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i don't get why you use a reflection instead of the real object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible the way you put it. **PHP can only load a class definition once.** After it's loaded and in memory, the only way to "refresh" it is to terminate the script and re-execute it. If you try re-including the file, you'll obviously get a "*class already defined error*". No matter how long your script runs, once the class definition is in memory, there's nothing you can change in it (unless you use a third-party extension).

The Reflection API works on the class definition in memory, not the one on the disk.

I think you have three options from here:

- **Work with the class definition on disk.** This means you cannot use reflection but must use a tokenizer/parser instead.
- **Tamper with the file so that the class is reloaded in another namespace.** This will greatly pollute your global namespace with a lot of other use-once namespaces, since once they're defined, they cannot be unloaded.
- **Execute the script that loads/modifies the class in a separate process.** When the process starts, it will load the class definition and will forget all about it when it terminates, producing the "refresh" effect you're looking for. This is obviously your best bet.

Comment: The root issue seems to be, as you mentioned, that reflection works on the copy of the object in memory, not on disk. So I changed the approach I was using. Rather than make a change and save it to disk, I just queued all of the changes, made them all at once, and wrote the file to disk one time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadClass()` method loads the class file contents into an array but it's not what loads the class definition into the PHP interpreter. It looks like your call to `class_exists()` is triggering the autoloader and that's what actually loads the class into PHP.

As far as I know it's not possible to "reload" a class definition that has already been loaded in a script. Trying to do so would crash your script with a fatal error.

I think you have two choices:

1. After editing and saving the class file, have your script redirect to itself and then exit. This will start the script over again and load the newly edited version of your class. Any parameters that were originally POSTed to your script will have to go into the query string when you redirect.
2. Use [runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) (a PECL extension) to remove the method from the class without reloading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don! I had this same problem recently. The approach that I ended up taking was to load the text of the class into a string file, as you have done. But create a "change buffer" to hold all of the changes that you want to make. For this, I used a private class variable array.
`private $del_text_buffer   = array();  //Array holding text to delete`

Once you have all of the changes you want to make in the buffer, make them all at once and write the modified file back to disk. The downside of this method is that you have to manually save the object file after you make changes, rather than automatically saving after each change. But the up side is that it works.

So, here is the new `loadClass()` function. As you can see, it is somewhat simplified. We are no longer calling methods to populate the 'class_text' and 'class_array' properties. This is because now they get populated only a single time, when the object is instantiated. They essentially become read-only reference copies of the code. Changes will be queued up and made in a single run.`public function loadClass() {
    if(!class_exists($this->class_name)) {
        $this->error = "Class name: '$this->class_name' was not found.";
    } else 
    {//Class is found. Load it and populate properties
        $this->oClass          = new $this->class_name;
        $this->oRClass         = new \ReflectionClass($this->oClass);
        $this->source_file     = $this->oRClass->getFileName();
        $this->error           = "";
        $this->class_namespace = $this->oRClass->getNamespaceName();
        $this->class_text      = file_get_contents($this->source_file);
        $this->class_array     = explode("\n", $this->class_text);
    }
}`
I also added a function called $array_extract, that pulls out a specified block of array elements, and returns it as a string.
`private function array_extract($haystack, $start_index, $end_index){
    $result = false;
    if(is_array($haystack)) {
        $extract = array();
        $n = 0;
        for($i=$start_index; $i<=$end_index; $i++) {
            $extract[$n] = $haystack[$i];
            $n++;
        }
        $extract = implode("\n", $extract);
        $result = $extract;
    }
    return $result;
}`
Now to delete a method, for instance, you use reflection to find it's start and end lines, pass those lines to `array_extract().`, which will return the contents of those lines as a string. You then push that string onto the delete buffer, which holds all deletes to be made.`public function deleteMethod($meth_name = "") {
    $result = false;
    $oMethod = $this->oRClass->getMethod($meth_name);
    //Find where method is located, and hack it out
    $start_index  = $oMethod->getStartLine() -1;
    $end_index    = $oMethod->getEndLine() -1;
    $del_string = $this->array_extract($this->class_array, $start_index, $end_index);
    array_push($this->del_text_buffer, $del_string);
    $this->num_changes++;
    //--- Delete the comment attached to the text, if any
    $comment_txt = $oMethod->getDocComment();
    if($comment_txt != "") {
        array_push($this->del_text_buffer, $comment_txt);
        $this->num_changes++;
    }
}`
So, `deleteMethod()` does not actually modify the `$class_text`, or `$class_array` variables. But rather, it finds the text that WILL be deleted, and pushes it onto the array for later processing.

The changes are actually processed when the object is save back to disk, as you can see in the `saveObject()` function. This function must be called only once at the end of processing. I am thinking of putting it into a destructor.
`public function saveObject() {
    if($this->num_changes) {
        $num_recs = count($this->del_text_buffer);
        for($i=0; $iclass_text = str_replace($this->del_text_buffer[$i], "", $this->class_text, $changes_made);
        }
        $result = file_put_contents($this->source_file, $this->class_text);
        $this->num_changes = 0;
    }
}`

Comment: Answering your own question is ok. Referring to youserlf in the third person is... hum... awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too today, and I stumbled over it for a while until I came upon this thread and consequently deemed it impossible.  However, there is a nice workaround: just edit the functions/methods in your file in the reverse order from which they were defined.  That way, the start/end lines are always correct.  You just have to document this well for future people who examine your code.